# SQLite and multiple writes

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am new to databases and I'm trying to decide which one would suit my needs the most.  I am in the planning stages of a program that will store directory references to thousands of PDF files at multiple locations (all under one domain).  Basically, all it will be is date, location, originator's name and link to the file in each of the fields within the database.  Nothing more (no files, nothing fancy). All I'll need to do with the database is sort fields by location, date, name of the originator -- that's it.  There will be instances where multiple writes would need to occur at the same time.  I've read up on SQLite website that only one write is supported at any given time.  Does it mean writes to a specific file or database period?

What I mean is that multiple records would need to be added from different clients at any given time, but the existing records would not need to be modified (and if they do, it would be done from a specific client).  To give a little bit more detail, what I'll have is several locations at which service application will be running in the background and listening to folders.  Once a file enters a folder, it gets renamed under a specific format and added to the database.  It is very likely that two folder listening apps would try to add files to the database at the same time.

Would I be able to accomplish this with SQLite or is it one write at any given time to the entire database? If only one write is possible, period, to the entire database, is there a way to implement some sort of spooling system (sort of like on a printer), where writes would wait in a queue with life timers on them?

If it's not possible, then I will look at MySQL. Cost is of a concern, so I'm steering towards these two.

Comment: I see "thousands" and "SQLite" in the same sentence, I start thinking, "Time to use a better database, like MySQL."  Regrettably, there's not enough detail to make a definitive suggestion - yes, I'm leaning towards MySQL, but you don't tell use how the data is structured.

Comment: @Makoto Hmm, SQLite doesn't support that many fields?  Even if it's not files themselves, but rather links to them?  Sorry, I can't provide more detail, I'm in learning stages when it comes to databases.

Comment: Well I'd hope you wouldn't store raw files in the database.  Again - you tell me nothing of the structure of your data.  I can't say definitively that SQLite would serve your purpose or not.  Nor do I know how many systems this would be across.  There's not enough detail to answer subjectively.

Comment: @Makoto Oh, no, no.  Just the links to the files themselves.  I edited the question a bit above in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one write can occur at the exact time, but by default writes are automatically queued and you can achieve thousands of writes per second.

The main concern is what type of application is this?  Is it a web application developed on one machine and deployed to a single other production machine?  Then the extra trouble of installing and maintaining MySQL is not a concern and you're better off using MySQL.  If this is a desktop application installed on many desktops, then using an embedded database is far easier for development, installation, and maintenance and in that case use SQLite.

Comment: The application will be deployed on an intranet.  I plan it to be an application that is installed on several machines (approximately 20 at this moment).  Each machine will have its own folders with files being added throughout the day (anywhere from 10 to 30 files a day).  There will be a background service part that will listen to the folders, rename the applications and add them to the database, and then there will be the front-end application that lets users interact with the database.  So, the database itself needs to be centralized on a single server.

Comment: Maybe a web-like application with MySQL, just like you suggest, would be the best course of action.